# Join two infinite streams in calcite SQL

Tags: java, sql, streaming, apache-calcite

I have created two infinite test streams in java. Both delivers random data.
Now I want to join these datasets und receive a result on every new arriving data.

The result is: Stream A is processed until it ends. Then stream B is processed until it ends.
I have to conclusions:

1. If stream A is infinite I will never get any results because stream B is ignored and it keeps reading A until Out of memory
2. Later arriving data in stream A will not be processed after the reading of A was completed (if A is finite)

So I have 2 questions: Am I doing something completly wrong or is calcite designed this way? If I am doing wrong, how can I achieve a parallel reading and processing of two infinite streams?

I have attached the source of my main class, the 2 stream-generating classes and the model.json.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver");
    Properties info = new Properties();
    info.setProperty("lex", "JAVA");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:model=" + "c:\\calcite\\model.json", info);
    CalciteConnection calciteConnection = connection.unwrap(CalciteConnection.class);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = 
            statement.executeQuery("select stream * from S.B b full outer join S.A a on a.ID = b.PRODUCT_ID");

    System.out.println("statement executed");
        final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        int n = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            buf.append(i > 1 ? "; " : "").append(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i)).append("=")
                    .append(resultSet.getObject(i));
        }
        System.out.println(buf.toString());
        buf.setLength(0);
    }
}





public abstract class Stream implements StreamableTable, ScannableTable{

public Schema.TableType getJdbcTableType() {
    return Schema.TableType.STREAM;
}

@Override
public boolean isRolledUp(String column) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean rolledUpColumnValidInsideAgg(String column, SqlCall call, SqlNode parent,
        CalciteConnectionConfig config) {
    return false;
}
public Table stream() {
    return this;
}
public Statistic getStatistic() {
    return Statistics.of(100d, ImmutableList.of());

}
}


public class StreamA extends Stream {
   public static  boolean wait = false;
   public Enumerable<Object[]> scan(DataContext root) {
    return Linq4j.asEnumerable(() -> new Iterator<Object[]>() {
        private final String[] items = { "paint1", "paper2", "brush3" };
        private int counter = 0;
        
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return true;
        }

        public Object[] next() {
            System.out.println("next A");
            
            final int index = counter++;
            
            return new Object[] { System.currentTimeMillis(), index , items[index % items.length]};
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        

        
    });
    
}



protected final RelProtoDataType protoRowType = a0 -> a0.builder().add("ROWTIME", SqlTypeName.TIMESTAMP)
        .add("ID", SqlTypeName.INTEGER).add("PRODUCT", SqlTypeName.VARCHAR, 10)
        .build();

public RelDataType getRowType(RelDataTypeFactory typeFactory) {
    return protoRowType.apply(typeFactory);
}
}





public class StreamB extends Stream {
   public static  boolean wait = false;
   public Enumerable<Object[]> scan(DataContext root) {
    return Linq4j.asEnumerable(() -> new Iterator<Object[]>() {
    
        private int counter = 0;
        
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return true;
        }

        public Object[] next() {
            System.out.println("next B");
            
            final int index = counter++;
            return new Object[] { System.currentTimeMillis(), index, (Math.abs((new Random()).nextInt())) % 4 +1, "Kauf "+index };
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        

    });
}



protected final RelProtoDataType protoRowType = a0 -> a0.builder().add("ROWTIME", SqlTypeName.TIMESTAMP)
        .add("ID", SqlTypeName.INTEGER).add("PRODUCT_ID", SqlTypeName.INTEGER).add("NAME", SqlTypeName.VARCHAR, 15)
        .build();

public RelDataType getRowType(RelDataTypeFactory typeFactory) {
    return protoRowType.apply(typeFactory);
}
}



{
 "version": "1.0",
 "defaultSchema": "dummy",
 "schemas": [
{
  "name": "S",
  "tables": [ {
    "type": "custom",
    "name": "A",
    "stream": {
      "stream": true
    },
    "factory": "de.mypackage.calcite.StreamFactory$FactoryA"
  },
{
    "type": "custom",
    "name": "B",
    "stream": {
      "stream": true
    },
    "factory": "de.mypackage.calcite.StreamFactory$FactoryB"
      
      }
      ]
}
  ]
}
```

Let's say: Isn't possible.
How can I use two infinite datastreams in windowed joins? in the calite doumentation I only found the rowtime as join condition, but this won't work, too

Comment: I don't understand how you think this could work even on a conceptual level.  Joins are (whole-)set operations.  You cannot compute the result of a join without considering the whole of both operands.  It is conceivable that partial results could be delivered while the inputs are being read, but at minimum, at least one of the inputs would need to be buffered somewhere, in its (to any given point point) entirety.  You cannot avoid running out of resources at some point unless there is a characteristic of the data that you can rely upon to trim that to finite buffering..

Comment: I know this can't work forever and I will get the oom-error. But thought I can get some partial data (in the book "Streaming Systems: The What, Where, When, and How of Large-Scale Data Processing chapter 9" there are some examples showing "undo"-operations after the matching join-data arrived. In the first step, the Left-Dataset arrived and joined "null"s. When the right-dataset is also arrived, there will be an undo-operation on the previous left-dataset and a new left-right-joined result is delivered

Comment: Of course you are free to write that, @EfGe, but it does not in any way surprise me that Calcite doesn't do it.  Note also that it is pointless to use an *outer* join for the conceptually-infinite case, especially a full outer join, because you don't know which rows from source A are unmatched with rows from source B until you have seen all the rows of source B, and *vice versa*.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to use infinite streams in windowed joins? Like 1-minute-window deliveres results every minute? The documentation only shows me the rowtime as join condition the way of processing seems like the same. https://calcite.apache.org/docs/stream.html#joining-streams-to-streams

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, @EfGe.  Are you asking for provisional results, based on a join model such as you presented earlier?  I don't know for sure, but I would be very surprised if Calcite provided such a thing.

Comment: I also think you have probably presented an XY problem. You should take a step back.  What underlying problem are you trying to approach by your proposal to join two infinite row sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calcite does not currently support stream-to-stream joins. You can find more information in [the documentation on streaming](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/stream.html#joining-streams-to-streams). I don't believe there has been recent progress, but you can follow the status of stream join support in [Calcite's issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-4125).

I'll add a few notes on how it's planned to work. It really only makes sense if you're doing so within a particular window. For this to work, you need to make use of a monotonic column in each stream such as `rowtime` so there can be a guarantee that progress can be made in the query.

Here's one example joining two streams of orders and shipments from the documentation:

```
SELECT STREAM o.rowtime, o.productId, o.orderId, s.rowtime AS shipTime
FROM Orders AS o
JOIN Shipments AS s
  ON o.orderId = s.orderId
  AND s.rowtime BETWEEN o.rowtime AND o.rowtime + INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
```

In this case, you can see there is a constraint that the shipment must occur within one hour of the order. In a case like this, Calcite would be able to make forward process in the query since `Orders.rowtime` and `Shipments.rowtime` are both monotonic.